# how to Set forcefully back camera and disable front camera in android

Tags: android

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 0);
            // ******** code for crop image
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);


            try {

                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Do nothing for now
            }
```

this code i have use for Open Camera   :

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
            try {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    photo = extras.getParcelable("data");                

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }
```

this code for return data  of bitmap please tell me how to set Camera always back not always front in android when i Open Camera please suggest me Solution for this .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force the use of a particular camera using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. There is no requirement for any camera app to honor the many undocumented extras that you are packaging on that `Intent`.

If you need that degree of control, use the camera APIs directly (e.g., `android.hardware.Camera`) and write your own camera code.

Comment: can u please Provide me Custom camera Example so that i can take picture @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to open Back Camera

```
   Camera cam = null;
  Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
  for (int camNo = 0; camNo < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); camNo++) {
 CameraInfo camInfo = new CameraInfo();
  Camera.getCameraInfo(camNo, camInfo);
 if (camInfo.facing.equals(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)) {
    cam = Camera.open(camNo);
}
}
   if (cam == null) {
  // no front-facing camera, use the first back-facing camera instead.
     // you may instead wish to inform the user of an error here...
   cam = Camera.open();
          }
```